Testing coroutines in Kotlin. How to handle delay
I changed part of my code by adding kotlin coroutines. Thats my function looks like now:
    fun deleteDataFromDb(@PathVariable id: String) {
        val user = authUser.user
        GlobalScope.launchWithMdc {
            JwtContext(user).use {
                dataService.deleteDataFormDb(id)
            }
        }
    }

And my one test doesn't work. This is a part of it:
        deleteDataFromDb(id).andExpect(
            MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk
        )

        getDataFromDb(id).andExpect(
            MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isNotFound
        ) //here is an error

The reason why my test doesn't work is simple. deleteDataFromDb the function did not end before the check was performed.
What is the best practise to handle this delay?

Well, for starters, never use GlobalScope.  Use a coroutine scope you control -- generally a test scope where you can wait for all tasks to end.

Okey I can change for couroutineScope. But still how to fix the test in best way ?

If you use runTest { ... } and use a TestScope, you can then use that scope in your code, and  call TestScope.advanceUntilIdle to wait for all active tasks (like the database operation) to finish.
